# Overstayed in Germany by a day, applying to work at US university

Tags: customs-and-immigration, germany, schengen-visas, us-visa, criminal-records

First, can I say whoever helps answer this I owe you extreme gratitude. This is a very important issue for me.

I am an Australian citizen who entered Germany in 2019 on a 3-month tourist visa, and I ended up overstaying by one day (accidentally by miscalculation).

I was taken to the police station within the airport and signed made to sign a few forms. I was given the forms but later threw them away, when moving house (they were bad reminders of a stressful time - I know this wasn't smart).

I don't really remember what the forms said. I think Form 1 was along the lines of "do you understand why you are being detained?" I think Forms 2 was along the lines of "do you give permission to share data". And Form 3 was along the lines of "you admit to an offense".

I asked what the consequences of this were and the officer said "no consequences" and then I was allowed to board my flight.

Flash forward to 2022 and I'm now being hired at a US university, and they want to know about any previous crimes and also this will involve a visa. I want to know three things:

1. Did I commit a crime (I suppose a misdemeanor?)
2. If so, what was the exact crime, and what would have those forms been?
3. Should I inform my employer about this incident (am I required to), and should I note it on the visa forms?

Thanks any help, or direction to any sources that would help.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it had been asked on an other stack exchange site, where it belongs.

Answer (score 2):

Your decision on how to proceed here (reveal or not reveal what happened in Germany) carries significant risk. If you do not reveal what happened in Germany, and whoever’s looking at your denial discovers that you’ve not been truthful, you risk having your employment offer rescinded and your visa application denied.

The prospective employer might not care enough to investigate a “no” answer. Even if they did investigate, their access to past immigration records of another country might be spotty or non-existent. The chances of being caught out here are unknown. But if you were caught out, you'd be seen to have lied on your application, which is unlikely to go over well.

You also need a US visa for this job. This increases the stakes substantially, as the US State Department visa examiner will look at both the substance of what you say in your application, as well any conflicts or differences between what you say in the application and what’s shown on other governmental records available to the examiner.

The visa examiner has significantly greater and easer investigative reach than the university. The US is party to significant international immigration information-sharing through the [Five Eyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Eyes) agreements. Australia is a member too. It’s reasonable to assume that the US State Department visa examiner will want to know whatever Australia knows about you. It’s also reasonable to assume that Germany, knowing your name and passport number, reported its actions to the Australian Passport Office, of the Department of Foreign Affairs and Trade.

If the Passport Office reports a German violation to the US State Department, and your visa application omits mentioning the issue, then you’ll be caught lying on your visa application. Your application will be denied.

On the other hand, if you answer truthfully, you will have a better chance that the violation will be seen as inconsequential, and ignored. Your overstay was short and the result of miscalculation, an inadvertence. People (including those who travel) err.  This should not be seen by anyone as a serious and disqualifying misstep.

Thus, the consistent advice given on this site: answer all the questions truthfully. You don’t have to answer questions not asked, but explain as necessary. Your statements should be clear, concise, and without emotion.

Comment: And this really belongs on [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com).

Comment: It has also been asked on expats, so we should not move it, as it will be closed as a duplicate. Maybe copy answer to there and then delete here.

Comment: @Willeke Yes, I just did that. And flagged this one for closure or deletion, too.